# Why useEffect doesn't fire on every render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx-react

My component has two `Rect.useEffect` hook

```js
const Example = ({ user }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    autorun(() => {
      console.log("inside autorun", user.count);
    });
  });

  // Only runs once
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Why not me?");
  });

  return <Observer>{() => <h1>{user.count}</h1>}</Observer>;
};
```

I update this component using `mobx`. It is re-rendered correctly. But `"Why not me?"` is printed only once.

As per [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

> By default, effects run after every completed render

This means `console.log("Why not me?");` too should run every time prop `user` is updated. But it doesn't. The console output is this

[image]

What's the reason behind this apparent inconsistency?

My complete code can be viewed here

[image: Edit mobx-useEffect query]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mobx, just like `Observer` component which provides a render function callback, `autorun` function also executes independently of the react lifecycle.

This behaviour happens because you have **user count as a observable variable**.

According to the mobx-react docs

> Observer is a React component, which applies observer to an anonymous
>   region in your component. It takes as children a single, argumentless
>   function which should return exactly one React component. The
>   rendering in the function will be tracked and automatically
>   re-rendered when needed.

and mobx docs

> When `autorun` is used, the provided function will always be triggered
>   once immediately and then again each time one of its dependencies
>   changes.

You can confirm this behvaior by logging directly inside the functional component and you will observer that the component is only rendered once

**EDIT:**

To answer your question

> If I change `useEffect` to this
>
> ```
> React.useEffect(autorun(() => {console.log("inside autorun", user.count)}));
> ```
>
> basically remove anonymous function from `useEffect` and just pass
>   autorun directly, then it is run only once. Why is it so? What's the
>   difference?

The difference is that `autorun` returns a `disposer function` which when run will dispose of the `autorun` and would not longer execute it.

**From the docs:**

> The return value from autorun is a disposer function, which can be
>   used to dispose of the autorun when you no longer need it.

Now what happens is that since useEffect executes the callback provided to it when it runs, the callback executed is the `disposer` function returned by autorun which essentially cancels your autorun.

Comment: That's a great explanation. If I change `useEffect` to this `React.useEffect(autorun(() => {console.log("inside autorun", user.count)}));`, basically remove anonymous function from `useEffect` and just pass `autorun` directly, then it is run only once. Why is it so? What's the difference?

Comment: @Andrew-Dufresne Updated the answer with an explanation

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your component doesn't rerender. `autorun` receives a callback and might call it independently from render.

`Example` component rerenders only when its parent rerenders or when its props change.

Use this code to observe what's really happening:

```
const Example = ({ user }) => {
  console.log('render');
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect autorun');
    autorun(() => {
      console.log("inside autorun", user.count);
    });
  });

  // Only runs once
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Why not me?");
  });

  return <Observer>{() => <h1>{user.count}</h1>}</Observer>;
};
```